# Split file into multiple small files, separate by the newline symbol

Tags: text-processing, split

Is there a utility that split file by newline symbol? e.g if a file contains the following lines,

```
aa
bbb
cccc
```

If I want to split it to 3 files, the desired output would be:

`aa`, `bbb` And `cccc` (in 3 different files)

I already checked the `split` command, it only cut file by file sizes, not what I want.

If I don't wrote a utility myself, is there any standard tool to use?

Comment: what should be filename ?

Comment: you want create file of each line ? I'm correct ?

Comment: sequential names: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164903/split-the-lines-of-a-text-file-into-separate-files

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, `split` does split by line if you use `-l` switch:

```
   -l, --lines=NUMBER
          put NUMBER lines per output file
```

so

```
split -l 1 inputfile
```

should do what you want.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk '{print > $0".txt" }'  inputfile
```

would create one file per unique line in inputfile named after the content of those lines (with a `.txt` extension). But beware that when the limit of concurrent open files is reached, some `awk` implementations will fail.

Or

```
awk '{f = "output_file." NR; print $0 > f; close(f)}' inputfile
```

To have numbered output files.

Comment: You may want to close() the output file after it's written, otherwise you'll run into the maximum number of open files limit with most awk implementations.

Comment: don't aware of that.. can you do that for me ? thanks..

Answer (score 3):

```
A=0
while IFS= read -r LINE ; do
  printf '%s\n' "$LINE" > newfile$A
  (( A++ ))
done < "$INPUTFILE"
```