# Split the lines of a text file into separate files

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, split

I have a text file that looks something like this:

```
foo
bar
zip
rar
tar
```

I need to use a bash script on OSX to make a new text file after every new line like this:

```
cat text1.txt
foo
cat text2.txt
bar
cat text3.txt
zip
cat text4.txt 
rar
cat text5.txt
tar
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`csplit`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/csplit.1.html). It does the job well, except that it's somewhat inflexible regarding the output file names (you can only specify a prefix, not a suffix) and you need a first pass to calculate the number of pieces.

```
csplit -f text -- input.txt '//' "{$(wc -l input.txt)}"
for x in text[0-9]*; do mv -- "$x" "$x.txt"; done
```

The GNU version, but not the OSX version, has extensions that solve both issues.

```
csplit -b '%d.txt' -f text -- input.txt '//' '{*}'
```

Alternatively, if `csplit` is too inflexible, you can use awk.

```
awk '{filename = sprintf("text%d.txt", NR); print >filename; close(filename)}' input.txt
```

Comment: `awk: text18.txt makes too many open files
 input record number 18, file ~/Desktop/namnlös mapp/flash varibales3.txt
 source line number 1`

Comment: @DisplayName Ooops yes, files need to be closed. Edited.

Answer (score 2):

Version with pure bash...

```
unset i; while read -r l; do echo $l > "text$((++i)).txt";done < text_file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the contents of the text file contains no spaces you could also use a for loop in Bash.

```
$ for x in $(<file.txt); do echo "$x" > text$((++i)).txt; done
```

#### Example

```
$ cat file.txt 
foo
bar
zip
rar
tar
```

Now with `$i` unset.

```
$ unset i
$ for x in $(<file.txt);do echo "$x" > text$((++i)).txt;done
$ ls -l text*
-rw-rw-r--. 1 slm slm 4 Oct 29 22:03 text1.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 slm slm 4 Oct 29 22:03 text2.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 slm slm 4 Oct 29 22:03 text3.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 slm slm 4 Oct 29 22:03 text4.txt
-rw-rw-r--. 1 slm slm 4 Oct 29 22:03 text5.txt
```

Confirming the results:

```
$ head text*
==> text1.txt <==
foo

==> text2.txt <==
bar

==> text3.txt <==
zip

==> text4.txt <==
rar

==> text5.txt <==
tar
```